# how to properly use jspdf custom fonts in fromHTML() method

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Iam trying to add custom fonts in jspdf. The pdf.addFont() method works only with pdf.text() and does not work with fromHTML() method. I need to use the custom fonts in fromHTML();  How can i add the Custom fonts in the fromHTML().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSPDF Custom Font Add not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590751/jspdf-custom-font-add-not-working)